# {"$":["'i' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."],"request":["The request field is required."]}}

Tags: ajax, post, controller

I'm simply trying to send this AJAX request to my controller but keep ending up with the error in the title, Everything works fine on swagger API so I'm assuming somehow I'm passing the data wrong on the ajax request? here is the request:

```
function submitForm(){
        
        var fullName = $("#name").find(":selected").val();
        console.log(fullName);
        var firstName = fullName.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
        console.log(firstName);
        var lastName = fullName.split(' ').slice(-1).join(' ');
        console.log(lastName);
        
        console.log($("#name").find(":selected").attr("name"));
        
    var formData = {
                id: null,
                type: 2,
                person: $("#name").find(":selected").attr("name"),
                firstName: firstName,
                lastName: lastName,
                dateCreated: new Date().toISOString(),
                dateModified: new Date().toISOString(),
                modifiedBy: "Web Application"
    };
        
        console.log(formData);
        
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'https://localhost:44398/api/Attendee1/InsertAttendee',
      data: formData,
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function(res){
          
          console.log(res)
      
          }
    });
}
```

Here is my Controller

```
 [HttpPost("InsertAttendee")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Attendee2>> InsertAttendee(Attendee2 request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Attendee2 Attendee2 = new Attendee2();
            Attendee2.Type = request.Type;
            Attendee2.Person = request.Person;
            Attendee2.FirstName = request.FirstName;
            Attendee2.LastName = request.LastName;
            Attendee2.DateCreated = request.DateCreated;
            Attendee2.DateModified = request.DateModified;
            Attendee2.ModifiedBy = request.ModifiedBy;

            var returnedId = new OutputParameter<int?>();
            try
            {
                await _context.GetProcedures().InsertAttendeeAsync(Attendee2.DateCreated, Attendee2.DateModified, Attendee2.FirstName, Attendee2.LastName, Attendee2.ModifiedBy, Attendee2.Person, Attendee2.Type, returnedId, null, cancellationToken);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, ex);
            }
            return CreatedAtAction("GetAttendee1", new { id = Attendee2.Id }, Attendee2);
            
        }
```

Attendee 2 Model

```
public class Attendee2
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Type { get; set; }
        public int? Person { get; set; }
        [StringLength(100)]
        [Unicode(false)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(100)]
        [Unicode(false)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
        public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Unicode(false)]
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    }
```

Full Error: {"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-f5e0489cf9bb95269b878874ccb4e152-3003e7f9f1a70d1d-00","errors":{"$":["'i' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."],"request":["The request field is required."]}}

Answer (score 0):

The Solution was to JSON.Stringify(formData).